# CSS inconsistency on Jobs section

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, stack-overflow-jobs

Fairly minor, but I happened to notice this in my notifications panel:

Jobs:
[image: Image on Jobs]

Main site:
[image: Image on main site]

The issue is caused by a CSS reset file only used on the Jobs section - I found both [cv-minimum.css](http://cdn-careers.sstatic.net/careers/less/views/cv-minimum.min.css?v=ae62f611f964) and [search-settings.css](http://cdn-careers.sstatic.net/careers/less/views/search-settings.min.css?v=29c20521ad31) containing the CSS:

```
*, *::before, *::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

This is in contrast to the main site's [all.css](http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/all.css?v=d9e4e45e8d1e) having `box-sizing: inherit;`.

Since the notifications area has a width defined to fit its content exactly and the borders on the box behave differently due to this CSS inconsistency, the icon no longer fits on the same line and is pushed down.

Oops.

Comment: Hm, not able to repro: http://goo.gl/zHmwBA

Comment: I don't think it should make a difference considering the wide support for `box-sizing`, but the problem was observed in IE11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has issue has been corrected for now. It was tested in IE11. The only way to completely solve this issue is to build out the topbar with widths, margins, and paddings built with `box-sizing: border-box`, but that would be a large(r) rewrite then we want to tackle right now (but we do want to do this!). So for now, we've reduced the `site-icon` margin-right from 5px to 2px.